# Need to create procedure to enter multiple data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created 1 procedure which will update 1 table through SSRS report.
Like in report, user will enter the data through which it will update the table. Only problem I am facing is I cannot enter multiple number at the same time.

I have a procedure like this.

```
   create procedure [dbo].[updating1] @up int  
   as  
   update test1 set Lotid=0
   where Lotid=@up  
   GO
```

What changes I have to make so That I can enter multiple number at the same time.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your procedure to accept table type as input parameter. Using table type parameter you can pass more than one `Lotid` as input and update the table

Creating user defined table type

```
Create type udt_Lotid table (up int)
```

Altering your procedure to accept udt as input and relevant changes in update query

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[updating1] (@up udt_Lotid READONLY)
as 
update T1 set Lotid=0
From test1 T1 
Join @up t 
  on t.up = t1.up
```

Comment: I am not able to create user defined table type. It is giving syntax error near table